# Recursion calling problem in xsl with following-sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, iteration, nodes

I have the following xml, which contains information of products. The description of each product sometimes appears in nexts rows before next product, because of after certain number of characters, the description is splitted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <row>
  <rowWords>5.00</rowWords>
  <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE1</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD3</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD4</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD5</rowWords>
  <rowWords>11.28</rowWords>
  <rowWords>56.40</rowWords>
 </row>
 <row>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD6</rowWords>
 </row>
 <row>
  <rowWords>6.00</rowWords>
  <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE2</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD3</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD4</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD5</rowWords>
  <rowWords>11.00</rowWords>
  <rowWords>66.00</rowWords>
 </row>
 <row>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD6</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD7</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD8</rowWords>
 </row>
 <row>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD9</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD10</rowWords>
 </row>
 <row>
  <rowWords>10.00</rowWords>
  <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE3</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
  <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
  <rowWords>10.00</rowWords>
  <rowWords>100.00</rowWords>
 </row>
  .
  . any amount of rows containing products
  . 
</root>
```

Descriptions as well as the number of products changes, so I don't know how to bring together descriptions of the products in a single line.

This is the xsl that I have already done.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="something">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/root">
 <a:Invoice>
  <Products>
   <xsl:for-each select="row[position()&gt;=5 and position()&lt;=last()-5]">
   <!-- With this if, i prevent create a product node with partial description-->
    <xsl:if test="number(rowWords[1])">
     <Product>
      <xsl:attribute name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="rowWords[1]"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="productCode"><xsl:value-of select="rowWords[2]"/></xsl:attribute>
      <!--Here is the problem (Thank you Dimitri) -->
      <xsl:attribute name="description">
        <xsl:call-template name="constructDescription">
            <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pPosition" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="unitValue"><xsl:value-of select="rowWords[last()-1]"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="amount"><xsl:value-of select="rowWords[last()]"/></xsl:attribute>
     </Product>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Products>
 </a:Invoice>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template name="constructDescription">
  <xsl:param name="pRow"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPosition"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pRow/*[position() >= 3 and position() &lt;= last() -2]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="$pRow/following-sibling::*[not(number(*[1])=number(*[1]))]">
        <xsl:call-template name="constructDescription">
            <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="$pRow/following-sibling::
                *[position()=number($pPosition)+1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output

```
    <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<a:Invoice>
  <Products>
    <Product quantity="5.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE1" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6 DESCRIPTIONWORD7 DESCRIPTIONWORD8 DESCRIPTIONWORD9 DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6 DESCRIPTIONWORD7 DESCRIPTIONWORD8 DESCRIPTIONWORD9 " unitValue="11.28" amount="56.40"/>
    <Product quantity="6.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE2" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6 DESCRIPTIONWORD7 DESCRIPTIONWORD8 DESCRIPTIONWORD9 " unitValue="11.00" amount="66.00"/>
    <Product quantity="10.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE3" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 " unitValue="10.00" amount="100.00"/>
  </Products>
</a:Invoice>
```

What's happening? The problem is when i call again constructDescription! But I don't know how to fix it!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're asking us to read a lot of XML. Is all of it required to illustate the problem?

Comment: Thank you, John! I changed the way I was asking! I expect it be more clear

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslrecur/ - may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation uses a named template, which when called with a parameter that is a `row` containing a product, produces a string with the full description**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowingDesc"
 match="row[not(number(*[1])=number(*[1]))]"
 use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[number(*[1])=number(*[1])][1])"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="constructDescription">
   <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="/*/*[1]"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="constructDescription">
    <xsl:param name="pRow"/>

    <xsl:for-each select=
      "$pRow/*[position() >= 3
             and
               not(position() > count($pRow/*) -2)
               ]
">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kFollowingDesc', generate-id($pRow))">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (yours, but well-formed and significantly truncated):

```
<root>
    <row>
        <rowWords>6.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD3</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD4</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD5</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD6</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD7</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD8</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD9</rowWords>
        <rowWords>11.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>66.00</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD10</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD11</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD12</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD13</rowWords>
    </row>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct description is produced**:

```
DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6 DESCRIPTIONWORD7 DESCRIPTIONWORD8 DESCRIPTIONWORD9 DESCRIPTIONWORD10 DESCRIPTIONWORD11 DESCRIPTIONWORD12 DESCRIPTIONWORD13
```

**Explanation**: This named template should be self-explanatory, except the test if some item is a number, which is:

```
number($x) = number($x)
```

this evaluates to `true()` exactly when `$x` is a number (or a value of any type that can be cast successfully to a number).

We are testing:

```
not(number(*[1])=number(*[1]))
```

which evaluates to `true()` only when the first `rowWords` child of the next row *is not* a number -- and this means it contains more description words.

**Finally**: All this, integrated into the OP's code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="something">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kFollowingDesc"
     match="row[not(number(*[1])=number(*[1]))]"
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::row[number(*[1])=number(*[1])][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <a:Invoice>
            <Products>
                <xsl:for-each select="row[number(*[1])=number(*[1])]">
                    <!-- With this if, i prevent create a product node with partial description-->
                    <xsl:if test="number(rowWords[1])">
                        <Product>
                            <xsl:attribute name="quantity">
                                <xsl:value-of select="rowWords[1]"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="productCode">
                                <xsl:value-of select="rowWords[2]"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <!--Here is the problem (Thank you Dimitri) -->

                            <xsl:variable name="vDescriptions">
                              <xsl:call-template name="constructDescription">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="."/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:attribute name="description">
                              <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($vDescriptions)"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="unitValue">
                                <xsl:value-of select="rowWords[last()-1]"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="amount">
                                <xsl:value-of select="rowWords[last()]"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </Product>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Products>
        </a:Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="constructDescription">
        <xsl:param name="pRow"/>

        <xsl:for-each select=
          "$pRow/*[position() >= 3
                 and
                   not(position() > count($pRow/*) -2)
                   ]
    ">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kFollowingDesc', generate-id($pRow))">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the new XML document he provided**:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <rowWords>5.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE1</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD3</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD4</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD5</rowWords>
        <rowWords>11.28</rowWords>
        <rowWords>56.40</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD6</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>6.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD3</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD4</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD5</rowWords>
        <rowWords>11.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>66.00</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD6</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD7</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD8</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD9</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD10</rowWords>
    </row>
    <row>
        <rowWords>10.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>PRODUCTCODE3</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD1</rowWords>
        <rowWords>DESCRIPTIONWORD2</rowWords>
        <rowWords>10.00</rowWords>
        <rowWords>100.00</rowWords>
    </row>   .   . any amount of rows containing products   .  
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a:Invoice xmlns:a="something">
<Products>
<Product quantity="5.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE1" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6" unitValue="11.28" amount="56.40" />
<Product quantity="6.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE2" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2 DESCRIPTIONWORD3 DESCRIPTIONWORD4 DESCRIPTIONWORD5 DESCRIPTIONWORD6 DESCRIPTIONWORD7 DESCRIPTIONWORD8 DESCRIPTIONWORD9 DESCRIPTIONWORD10" unitValue="11.00" amount="66.00" />
<Product quantity="10.00" productCode="PRODUCTCODE3" description="DESCRIPTIONWORD1 DESCRIPTIONWORD2" unitValue="10.00" amount="100.00" />
</Products>
</a:Invoice>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri. Thanks for your answer! I'm reviewed it and i don't understand how to merge my code with yours, lol! If you want to help me again, I'll be grateful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also integrated your code, Do you see it? But I can't get the goal yet!

Comment: @jechaviz: I edited my answer and also added a final part where the named template is integrated into your code and produces the wanted results. :)